# Service and PendingIntent

Tags: android, service, android-pendingintent

when I read the official document "Services", there are some sentences:

> However, if you want the service to send a result back, the client that starts the service can create a PendingIntent for a broadcast (with getBroadcast()) and deliver it to the service in the Intent that starts the service. The service can then use the broadcast to deliver a result.

According to the description of the document, How should I implement the content described in the document above?

Comment: What do you intend to do?

Comment: This is the description of system Services. if you want to implement you local service, you should not to do like this, just send broadcast in your service.